# How to run a shell script file whenever a new mail is received in Unix mailbox server?

Tags: shell, unix, sendmail

I need to execute a .sh file whenever a new mail is received in mailbox server (UNIX). How can i do it? I am new to Shell scripting.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This is typically done by putting `|/path/to/script` in the user's `.forward` file, but it depends on the specific mail software.

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Sendmail/Part+II+Administration/Chapter+13.+Mailing+Lists+and+.forward/13.7+The+Users+.forward+File/ for a bit of a description.

Comment: The above comments were helpful. Also, can I forward the mails based on specific conditions using .forward?

Answer (score 0):

Standard suggestion is to use something like `procmail` program.  It can be configured to process messages delivered to user's mailbox.  procmail can execute custom script for specific email e.g. based on sender, subject and size.

On many linux system sendmail uses procmail by default for deliveries to user's mailbox.
In such case all you need is `~/.procmailrc` script.

Which MTA/SMTP server do you use?  [see SMTP greeting via `telnet localhost 25`]

Comment: I am using Sendmail.

Comment: Take a look at line starting with `Mlocal` in your `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`. `P=` will show you which program sendmail uses for deliveries to local mailboxes.  You need no configuration changes if it is procmail or sensible-mda.

Comment: I  checked it...it is not procmail/sensible-mda. What should be done now?

Comment: Which specific program your sendmail uses as local mailer program?  Does your sendmail support `~/.forward` files? [It is another way to integrate `procmail`]

Comment: Procmail is not available in it.

Comment: Could you name SMTP server installed and specificy OS/distribution you use?